# Modification of J1939 C Library for PIC32

Tags: c, pic32, j1939

I am working on a project based on J1939 Interface. I am using J1939 C Library for PIC 18 devices (AN930), I am wondering how can I modify this library to work with PIC32MX795F512L device?
I am not the expert level programmer and started working on PIC32 couple of month ago.
Please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: I am referring AN930 Document from Microchip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the library was developed the right way, then you only need to find out the clock that controls the timing for the messages; and route it to the right configuration; also you need to identify the buffer where you are going to be receiving the messages, and route it to the library.

Answer (score 0):

That library is outdated and devs stopped updating it. It is designed for C18 compilers. If you want to use that library in XC18 or any other compiler you have to make some major changes in J1939.c file. I do not recommend to spend your time with it, you can implement new one by refering datasheet of your microcontroller, it would be so much easier. Good Luck!